# How to interpolate two list in R in a 3º list?

Tags: r

How I do that :

Example:

```
list1 = ("1","2","3")
list2= ("4","5","6")
```

and `list3 = ("1","4","2","5","3","6")`

Comment: What to do when one of the lists have different size of the second ?

Answer (score 3):

Here´s a simple approach

```
> c(rbind(list1, list2))
[1] "1" "4" "2" "5" "3" "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are lists

```
list1 = list("1","2","3")
list2= list("4","5","6")
```

then

```
unlist(rbind(list1, list2))
```

if they are vecotrs

```
list1 = c("1","2","3")
list2= c("4","5","6")
```

then @Jibers' solution

```
c(rbind(list1, list2))
```

Comment: What to do when one of the lists have different size of the second ?

Comment: Could you provide an example and what the result you'd like to be.

Comment: list1 = list("1","2","3","4","5")
list2= list("6","7","8")
What should I do  ?

Comment: Is your preferred result then `[1] "1" "6" "2" "7" "3" "8" "4" "5"` ?

Comment: Then try `unlist(c(unlist(rbind(list1[1:length(list2)], list2)), list1[(length(list2)+1):length(list1)]))` here the length of `list1` is `>` than the length of `list2`

Answer (score 0):

We could create a function using `order` based on sequence of the `list/vector`.  This can also work with unequal lengths.

```
 finterp <- function(x1, x2) {
    c(x1, x2)[order(c(seq_along(x1), seq_along(x2)))]
  }
```

Assuming that the objects are 'vectors'

```
finterp(list1, list2)
#[1] "1" "4" "2" "5" "3" "6"

finterp(list1, list3)
#[1] "1"  "7"  "2"  "8"  "3"  "9"  "10"
```

If 'list1' and 'list2' are 'lists'

```
  list1 <- as.list(list1)
  list2 <- as.list(list2)

  finterp(list1, list2)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "1"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "4"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "2"

 #[[4]]
#[1] "5"

 #[[5]]
 #[1] "3"

 #[[6]]
 #[1] "6"
```

#### data

```
list1 <- c("1","2","3")
list2 <- c("4","5","6")
list3 <- c("7", "8", "9", "10")
```